# Fail to catch exceptions in c++: failure to identify exception type

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    try {
        cout << "Please input your age: " << endl;
        int age;
        cin >> age;

        if (age > 100 || age < 0) {

            throw 130.1;
            throw 101;
        }
            cout << "Good input\n";

    }

    catch (char e) {
        cout << "Wrong input as char " <<e<< endl;
    }
    catch (int e) {
        cout << "Wrong input as int " <<e<< endl;
    }
    catch (float e) {
        cout << "Wrong input as double " <<e<< endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Wrong " << endl;
    }
}
```

Why when I enter `103.1` & `101`, exceptions caught go to `catch (...)` instead of the respective `catch(float e)` & `catch (int e)`.

Comment: then, how can I handle exceptions of multiple data type, with each type having unique exception message to display? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`130.1` is a `double` literal, so you need a `catch (double)` for that one (if you want to `throw` a `float` then use `throw 130.1f;`).

Program control never reaches `throw 101;`, so `catch (int)` is redundant.

Comment: then, how can I handle exceptions of multiple data type, with each type having unique exception message to display? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `130.1` is a [double literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal),

> suffix, if present, is one of f, F, l, or L. The suffix determines the type of the floating-point literal:
>
> ```
> (no suffix) defines double
> f F defines float
> l L defines long double
> ```

You need to change `catch (float e)` to `catch (double e)`.

2. `throw 101;` is placed after `throw 130.1`, so it won't be executed at all, then impossible to enter `catch (int e)` block.